# Как передать текст из окна приложения в функцию соединения с БД?

Tags: python, postgresql

Не удаётся передать значение из окна в функцию и создать соединение с БД, затем создать таблицу.
Можно ли так создать таблицу? Я этого ещё не знаю так как не могу соединиться с БД.
Пробовал создать переменные и с помощью format их вставлять в функцию. Не получилось. Получилось только в одной функции передать значение из окна в функцию с кнопкой и по этой кнопке выводить значение в print. Код этой программы выложил под проблемной программой. Ещё выложил код где можно посмотреть что получается при передаче значения через переменную.

```
from appJar import gui
import postgresql

app = gui('Программа успеваемости школьников', '1000x500')

app.addLabelEntry('Имя пользователя')
app.addLabelEntry('Пароль')
app.addLabelEntry('IP')
app.addLabelEntry('Port')
app.addLabelEntry('Название БД')


# такой должна быть переменная db = postgresql.open('pq://user:password@host:port/database')
def connectDb():
    db = '\'' + 'pq://' + app.getEntry('Имя пользователя') + ':' + app.getEntry('Пароль') + '@' + app.getEntry(
        'IP') + ':' + app.getEntry('Port') + '/' + app.getEntry('Название БД') + '\''
    global conDb
    conDb = postgresql.open(db)

#сначала создаём соединение, а затем создаём таблицу
def press(button):
    if button == 'Подключиться к БД':
        connectDb()
    elif button == 'Создать таблицу':
        conDb.execute(
            'CREATE TABLE school_achievement (scholar_id numeric , scholar_name text, scholar_assessment numeric)')


app.addButtons(['Подключиться к БД', 'Создать таблицу'], press)

app.go()
```

Вот код программы где получается передать текст из окна во вторую функцию и вывести его по кнопке:

```
from appJar import gui
import postgresql

app = gui('Программа успеваемости школьников', '1000x500')

name = app.addLabelEntry('Имя пользователя')

def c():
    db = "pq" + app.getEntry('Имя пользователя')
    return db


def press(button):
    if button == 'Ввести':
        print(c())


app.addButtons(['Ввести'], press)

app.go()
```

Вот код где видно что передаёт функция ввода из окна и в этом случае она передаёт не текст из окна:

```
from appJar import gui

app = gui('Программа успеваемости школьников', '1000x500')

name = app.addLabelEntry('Имя пользователя')


def c(name):
    db = "pq" + str(name)
    return db


def press(button):
    if button == 'Ввести':
        c(name)
        print(c(name))


app.addButtons(['Ввести'], press)

app.go()
```

Comment: `global db` должно быть внутри функции выше записи в переменную. И второе - функция `connectDb` у вас нигде не вызывается. Логично было бы чтобы у вас была еще кнопка "подключиться к базе", на нажатие которой вы бы повесили вызов `connectDb`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это не помогло. Я исправил код и выложил в вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя строка соединения в итоге выглядит как
'\'pq://1:2@3:4/5\''
Убери лишние кавычки в начале и конце

Answer (score 0):

По двум последним фрагментам. `name` - это не текст из поля ввода, а само поле ввода. В функцию нужно передать или `app.getEntry('Имя пользователя')`, или `name.get()` (т.к. `name` по сути это объект класса `tk.Entry` из библиотеки tkinter):

```
from appJar import gui

app = gui('Программа успеваемости школьников', '1000x500')
name = app.addLabelEntry('Имя пользователя')

def c(name):
    db = "pq" + name
    return db


def press(button):
    if button == 'Ввести':
        print(c(app.getEntry('Имя пользователя')))


app.addButtons(['Ввести'], press)

app.go()
```

или

```
from appJar import gui

app = gui('Программа успеваемости школьников', '1000x500')
name = app.addLabelEntry('Имя пользователя')

def c(name):
    db = "pq" + name
    return db


def press(button):
    if button == 'Ввести':
        print(c(name.get()))


app.addButtons(['Ввести'], press)

app.go()
```